# Mysql server won't start on XAMPP in Linux

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, lampp

Hello I'm running Linux Mint 19 and I tried to install Xamp from the official website , everything seems to be perfect the installation was successfully completed but then I noticed that the MYSQL database server won't start I can head to local/dashboard standard page but when I'm trying to go to PHPMyAdmin it doesn't work it shows this message.

```
Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also, ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: Permission non accordée (13)

session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: /opt/lampp/temp/)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try reinstalling xampp and change $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie'
 in config.inc.php file.

Then,

Open the terminal and try running this command:

```
chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp
```